# The argument type 'Brightness' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'. On statusBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I try to change to color of the statusBarColor to dark but it says error

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Brightness.dark));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Colors.black` instead of `Brightness`.

Or if you want to keep the background color use a semi-transparent color like `Colors.black45` or change manually with `Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

statusBarColor: Colors.red,

statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android (dark icons)

statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, // For iOS (dark icons)